# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Almofire.framework Image not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Please read following details before answer :

I have 
**Xcode 9.3**
and OS **10.13.4 macOS High Sierra**.

**Step 1:** Create new Xcode Project.

**Step 2:** Clean **Derive Data** folder.

**Step 3:** Uninstall CocoaPods. ReInstall CocoaPods.

**Step 4:** Clean Pod Catch as per this link.
[How to clear or clean specific pod cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428752/how-to-clear-or-clean-specific-pod-cache)

**Step 5:** Install Almofire using cocoapods.(**Note:** almofire or any other pods.)

**pod 'Alamofire'** && pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'

**step 6:** Open **ProjectName.xcworkspace** and Build project.

Error : Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ippy.png)

To Solve this error I do [Solution of above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO72q.png)

**[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks:** Enable script when running.

**Step 7:** Run Application: Application Crash with below error

> **dyld:** Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>
> **Referenced from:** /Users/rigel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9B2BC541-696F-4E44-8D5D-0CD4A07FF18F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4268ED9E-AE44-4C0A-BE9A-472C689D67E8/almotest.app/almotest
>
> **Reason:** image not found
>   [Crash Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3kNn.png)

NOTE:

> **And when I try to run this application on other mac it is working fine. Without error**

Please give me proper solution of this error.
what I have to do.

Comment: which OS version you are using and which version of cocoapods you are using. make sure both are updated

Comment: A general advice on third party issues. Do check the GitHub issues (Closed preferably) other than stack overflow. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/101

Comment: I have latest OS version 10.13.4  and latest cocoapods version 1.5.0 and Xcode version 9.3, @Sumanth

Comment: @Nitish thanks for your replay.

But when i am going to run same code in another MAC it is working fine.
what about that?

Comment: Just a note. **pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'** is the latest one. Try changing to this.

Comment: @Nitish **pod 'Almofire','~>4.7'** not working.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add Alamofire framework in Embedded binaries

Comment: error: /Users/rigel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/almotest-eskarskhigrggyamlsfbkepeyaao/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory

Comment: **This error return when adding framework in** Embedded Binaries
and this framework display with red color.

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

error: /Users/rigel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/almotest-eskarskhigrggyamlsfbkepeyaao/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory

Comment: Can u share your project?

Comment: There is no OLD project.
I just create a new project. and install pods using cocoapods.

Comment: Shall I send a project with Alamofire installed?

Comment: How i can send project to you.

Comment: @user9618103 Hi,I am also getting same error.Did you find any solution?