# React Native Pod Install fails on

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

pod install fails, it seems the FrozenError and the BadURIError below to be the cause :

```
CocoaPodsError: Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: pod exited with non-zero code: 1
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby

    stderr: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin20/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/cedricnicolas/Downloads in PATH, mode 040707\n' +
      '\u001b[33m\n' +
      "[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/auth' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v8.4.3 but found v8.4.1, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.\u001b[0m\n" +
      '\u001b[33m\n' +
      "[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/storage' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v9.0.0 but found v8.4.1, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.\u001b[0m\n" +
      "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)\n" +
      "\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'\n" +
      "
      "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb:1490:in `find_proxy': relative URI: /Users/cedricnicolas/Documents/DizzitupSource.nosync/dizzitup/client/dizzitapp/node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec (URI::BadURIError)\n" +
```

I have tried many things, my RC version is :
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.66.3

Any clue ?

Comment: where did you run this command? in the root of the project? or in `ios` folder ?

Comment: I ran `pod install` in the ios folder. Problems starts just after the following output line : `Fetching podspec for "Folly" from "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"`. 
Note that if I try to build the project from Xcode I have a completely different error : `<Project Folder>/ios/dizzitup/AppDelegate.h:1:9: React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found`

Comment: Okay, thanks for the extra details, do you try to remove and clean **pods** and install fresh packages? take a look for **complete cleanup** in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46428793/5737950

Comment: I did follow the instructions given by your link. No change, still the same error. Note that when I do `pod cache list` after `pod install`, the list is empty

Comment: I have found the solution. For a reason that I can't explain my package.json file have been updated : initially was `react-native": "0.62.2"` and has been updated to `react-native": "^0.66.3"`. I went back to 0.62.2 and it worked finally. Thanks for your support.

Comment: hopefully, you find the answer, I suggest you add the answer for future readers

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix does not work in my case. After a complete clean and reset of pods, I still get the `Folly... can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)`. My issue may be related to `Apple M1` or `react-native: 0.64.1`. At this point, I have no idea.

Comment: Same here @MikeS.