# Debug connection drops between Android Studio and iOS simulator (iPhone 13)

Tags: android-studio, ios-simulator

I bought an old Mac so that I could build my Flutter app for iOS. But even when I just start a new Flutter project and try to run the demo app on my iOS simulator, the app keeps crashing, and this is the only output I get:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           48.5s
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader failed unexpectedly
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

If I close the app on the simulator and open it again, it actually runs fine! So there is nothing wrong with the building or the code, it seems... But still, the connection drops. Why?

When I ran `flutter attach`, I got this output:

```
Syncing files to device iPhone 13...                               12.8s

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

 Running with sound null safety 

An Observatory debugger and profiler on iPhone 13 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:61007/KV20anKK53k=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on iPhone 13 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9100?uri=http://127.0.0.1:61007/KV20anKK53k=/
Lost connection to device.
```

I have tried `flutter clean` and "Invalidate caches and restart" as well as `pub upgrade` and `pod update` but nothing works.

Any tips?

### Flutter doctor

This is my `flutter doctor` output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 11.6.7 20G630 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at /Users/karolinahagegard/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (5 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/karolinahagegard/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • 4EA7D6B9-5026-4FE8-8904-0A48B7B3253C • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)    • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.6.7 20G630 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.79

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

### Mac specs

Some info about the computer:

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,1
  Processor Name:   Dual-Core Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed:  2,6 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 3 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   8 GB
  System Firmware Version:  433.120.6.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 2.16f68
```

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version:   macOS 11.6.7 (20G630)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 20.6.0
  Boot Volume:  Untitled
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  System Integrity Protection:  Enabled
  Time since boot:  19 days 2:45
```

Comment: for me restart the laptop solves the problem 

Comment: Really? Well, it didn't for me... but good for you! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so how I finally resolved this... or "resolved" this, was I downloaded a new simulator that works.  :

1. Open XCode
2. Go to XCode > Preferences > Components, where there should be a list of downloadable simulators
3. Click on the download symbol to the left of the simulator you want to download.

[image: screenshot of downloading simulator]

I'm suspecting the problem is related to my Mac not being very powerful...

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Mac helped finally ...